# Task planing/Scheduling software

Tags: pm-software

I'm looking for software for organizing a "workout routine". Not weights but things in general where I want an organized plan of action to accomplish a long term goal.

Essentially I want something that lets me give a list

1. Do X
2. Do Y
3. Do Z

But of course more "supped up"(the more features the better). I do not necessarily want to tie this to time since I may not start each thing at the exact same time or may have to miss things.

I would like to be able to add notes, possibly even links to pdfs and show images.

All the software I have looked at tend to be for the profession and is organized generally in time. I want something that I can use to refer to so I can organize my "workout" in a coherent and consistent way each time I do it and not skip around or miss things unintentionally.

To be clear, I have a set of tasks I want to accomplish per day and per week. The tasks have no specific time frame(I may start them at 9am or 1pm) but generally should be sequential but not always.

Essentially a mix of a "to do" list and project management. The main thing is to be able to present the tasks in a nice way and easy to follow with possible side information(pre and post information such as info about the task and "success" of the task).

http://www.pagico.com/

Seems to be about the closest I have seen. It should be a modern program and not something from win3.1. Most of the software I've seen looks quite dated and their web sites look like they came straight from 1999.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not enough info - what project left cycle management method do you use, what tools do your developers use? P.S. Google Chrome has some PM extensions that look interesting if a browser hosted tool is OK for you.

Comment: huh? developers? This is for personal management i.e., PIMs. I have a workout or practice routine I want to perform every day and be able to break it down into different things to practice. What is important is that I don't want to set specific times.

Comment: If this is every day, this is by definition not a project, and not appropriate for PM:SE

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace  check out the second sentence of the OP's question, "...where I want an organized plan of action to accomplish a **long term goal.**"

Comment: here is a project management framework for Eclipse that we are developing http://www.lowcoupling.com/mdpm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something to install yourself on a server like Redmine, Trac, or other open source project management tools (just check out [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_project_management_software)).

Or try out one of the many SaaS (software as a service) task/TODO list tools out there, like Remember the milk or [similar tools](http://alternativeto.net/software/remember-the-milk/). Or more project management oriented tools like Wrike or [similar](http://alternativeto.net/software/wrike/).

Even professional tools used in software development, like Mingle, JIRA and others might just work for your purpose (and are fairly cheap or even free for small teams).
Or, if you don't mind using Eclipse for this, the [Mylyn tool](http://eclipse.org/mylyn) comes with a task list with scheduling and free integrations with many open source issue trackers. But that's very much focussed on development area.

I thought one of those SaaS providers linked above would be suited best. Having a browser interface just works great for using it on any device you want. Even Windows 3.1

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at some of them and see which ones might work. Remember the milk looks interesting but again, it's time based. I'm trying to get away from setting specific tasks at a specific time since I never be able to do it at that time.

Comment: The alternative.to has a bunch of productivity apps I'll have to search through. Some even allow for daily tasks which is what I want. Not sure how limited they are though. Stack Exchange also has a personal productivity management forum where this question would be more appropriate(I didn't see it when looking the first time though)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this [online weekly planner](http://weekplan.net). It doesn't require to enter any time, and you have set recurring weekly tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend giving Toodledo.com a try.  It allows you to create tasks with just about any fields you want.  If you don't want to add a start date or due date, you don't have to.  I'm not sure if you can create recurring/daily tasks in the free version, but you can in the paid version.  There are also iOS and Android apps, so you can easily bring your list with you to the gym.

I also recommend picking up one of Michael Linenberger's books on time management/project management.  He has developed a strategy, which was originally intended for use with Microsoft Outlook's task tools, but can easily be applied using tools like Toodledo.  While he describes the system in the context of the day to day tasks of knowledge professionals, it can easily be adapted to your scenario and fitness goals.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at this [guide for work management](http://www.twproject.com/WorkManagementWithTeamwork.htm).

The guide is a user manual for Teamwork software but they cover interesting aspects of work management with practical examples.

We work in a similar way as you do, using issue organizer and time tracking and we are happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a Kanban board. Try www.trello.com.